# fmaf weird performance

Tags: c++, linux, performance, g++, intel

I'm experiencing an huge performance decrease using the `fmaf` function over the usage of `*` and `+`. I'm on two Linux machines and using g++ 4.4.3 and g++ 4.6.3

On two different machines the following code runs faster if the `myOut` vector is filled without the usage of `fmaf`.

server with g++ 4.6.3 and Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 @ 2.00GHz

```
$ ./a.out fmaf
Time: 1.55008 seconds.
$ ./a.out muladd
Time: 0.403018 seconds.
```

server with g++ 4.4.3 and Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650  @ 2.67GHz

```
$ ./a.out fmaf
Time: 0.547544 seconds.
$ ./a.out muladd
Time: 0.34955 seconds.
```

Shouldn't the `fmaf` version (apart to avoid an extra roundup and then be more precise) be faster?

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "missing parameter: 'muladd' or 'fmaf'"
              << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
  }
  struct timeval start,stop,result;
  const size_t mySize = 1e6*100;

  float* myA = new float[mySize];
  float* myB = new float[mySize];
  float* myC = new float[mySize];
  float* myOut = new float[mySize];

  gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
  if (!strcmp(argv[1], "muladd")) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mySize; ++i) {
      myOut[i] = myA[i]*myB[i]+myC[i];
    }
  } else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "fmaf")) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mySize; ++i) {
      myOut[i] = fmaf(myA[i], myB[i], myC[i]);
    }
  } else {
    std::cout << "specify 'muladd' or 'fmaf'" << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
  }

  gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
  timersub(&stop,&start,&result);
  std::cout << "Time: " <<  result.tv_sec + result.tv_usec/1000.0/1000.0
            << " seconds." << std::endl;

  delete []myA;
  delete []myB;
  delete []myC;
  delete []myOut;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is called *vectorisation*. Compare the assembly code produced by g++ 4.4.6 for both sections of your code when compiled with `g++ -O3 -S`:

the `muladd` part:

```
.L10:
    movaps  %xmm2, %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm2, %xmm1
    movlps  (%rbx,%rax), %xmm0
    movlps  (%r12,%rax), %xmm1
    movhps  8(%rbx,%rax), %xmm0
    movhps  8(%r12,%rax), %xmm1
    mulps   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm2, %xmm1
    movlps  0(%rbp,%rax), %xmm1
    movhps  8(%rbp,%rax), %xmm1
    addps   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, 0(%r13,%rax)
    addq    $16, %rax
    cmpq    $400000000, %rax
    jne     .L10
```

All those `*ps` perform operations over *packed single precision* numbers. These are SSE instructions and hence each pack consists of 4 consecutive elements of each array.

The loop which implements the `fmaf` version is:

```
.L14:
    movss   (%rbx,%r14,4), %xmm0
    movss   0(%rbp,%r14,4), %xmm2
    movss   (%r12,%r14,4), %xmm1
    call    fmaf
    movss   %xmm0, 0(%r13,%r14,4)
    addq    $1, %r14
    cmpq    $100000000, %r14
    jne     .L14
```

Here scalar SSE instructions are used to move the data one array element at a time **and** a function call to `fmaf` is made on each iteration.

The vector part of the loop is longer but executes 4x less iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Intel Xeon processors, as far as I know, do not support fused-multiply-add instructions. Wikipedia indicates these are available on AMD Piledriver and Bulldozer architecture processors, and Intel won't introduce them until Haswell/Broadwell in 2013/14. So, without direct instruction support, the `fmaf` function is likely compiled as an actual function call that emulates the instruction. Thus, there's function call overhead plus the actual multiply and add instructions. The non-`fmaf` option produces inline multiply and add instructions, without the function call overhead, so it's considerably faster. When in doubt, use `g++ -S`, and inspect the generated assembly code.

In addition, the inline code can be much better optimized and even vectorized (as noted in another answer), but of course, the results of that depend on which compiler and your exact flags you pass in compilation.

Comment: “function call overhead plus the actual multiply and add instructions”: Implementing `fmaf` of a processor that does not provide it as an instruction requires more than a multiplication and an addition. Here is how libc does it, with a change of FPU rounding mode: http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2010-10/msg00007.html